# Recursion in Array

Tags: c#, recursion

I have homework that i need to do, my exercise is Recursion:

> Given a backpack that can withstand the load of a num kg, and X data objects them want to take a walk.
>   For each object given its weight. Need to check whether there is any combination of objects that allows
>   Fully utilize the allowable load backpack.
>
> Write a recursive method that accepts a Boolean parameters allowable load of the backpack - num
>   And an array that contains the weights of the objects. The method will return true if the objects can be picked up the same weight
>   Allowable load rucksack and false if not. Also, the system will print the weights of objects
>   Fulfilling the conditions (if any). If more than one combination - printed one.
>   I can assume that the array is full of positives numbers
>
> for example:
>
> for `num = 10` and object list `4, 1, 15, 7, 12' 3' 9` the return is true and the function will print 1, 7, 12
>
> for `num = 12` and object list `18, 5, 3, 11` the return is false

This is what i have try:

```
    public static bool isFull (int[] arr, int num)
    {
        return isFull(arr, 0, num, 0);
    }

    public static bool isFull(int[] arr, int i, int num, int sum)
    {
        if (i == arr.Length)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if (arr[i] < num)
            {
                return isFull(arr, i + 1, num - sum, sum);
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit reluctant to give you the complete solution as this is after all homework, but here are some hints:

- As you are recursing through the array, you need to add the weight of the picked item to the subtotal of the weight so far (`sum` in your code)
- For each item you basically have two choices: either you pack them, or you leave them. I don't see this logic in your code. It's basically picking every item. Or perhaps none of them since you're not adding the weight (see previous item). You can solve this by actually **making two recursive calls** instead of one: one where you pick the item, and one where you don't.
- When you reach the end of the array, you are returning `true`. However, if you've reached the end and your `sum` does not equal `num`, you've actually failed to find a solution.
- I found it easiest to print the picked items in reverse order, on unwinding the call stack.

The method signatures you've defined can be used without changes, but the code itself needs to change quite a bit.